# Apache Cordova for WinPhone 7: HTML5 input type keyboard on focus

Tags: html, plugins, cordova, windows-phone

I'm working on Cordova application for Windows Phone 7. 
Here is my trouble. I have some fields like:

- `<input type="number"/>`:  with type number
- `<input type="date"/>`:  with type date

So, here I need digital keyboard to be shown on focus in first case and date picker in second case. On windows phone devices ordinary keyboard is displayed nevertheless the input type. 
Can you suggest any suitable workarounds for my case? I assume I'll probably have to create some cordova plugin - maybe somebody experienced the same problem before and can provide me with some code snippets/links/advices.

Regards, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've found beautiful Cordova plugin for DateTimePicker(and not only). Please, see https://github.com/sgrebnov/jqmobile-metro-theme.

Regards, Paul